# How do I route to a specific screen after clicking on a local push notification wherein my pushNotification.configure method is in index.js file

Tags: react-native, react-native-push-notification

Index.js file is the base file where in I call AppRegestiry and load App component and in index.js file, I have PushNotification.configure method. I am using react-native-push-notification library and Firebase cloud messaging service but always sending local notification. When I click on this notification, I want to route to a specific screen.Should I have to use Firebase or notifee for sending notifications to handle the clicking event?

As the index file is out of navigation Container , routing is not working.I can pass props to every component from index.js where i listen to notification being clicked.